# MaxListenersExceededWarning in Node JS Express App

Tags: node.js, mongoose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dialogflow-es, sigint

I am deploying a Node JS express app for a Dialogflow webhook on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The app uses mongoose to save data to mongoDB. There are four connection events (connected/ disconnected/ error/ process end). My console log gives the following warning: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 connected listeners added to [NativeConnection]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
I do not want to suppress the warning by adding more event listeners as I don't think more listeners are necessary. When I examine the log closely, I can see that the node app never terminates, and the process end event is never fired. A link to the log is at the end of this post. Below is the code I use for the different events. Note that the events are being triggered in two areas in the webhook code: (1) in the default welcome intent (to connect early to the DB to ensure that the data will be quickly pushed to DB later when needed) and (2) in the database_request function that is being called in the very last intent when user confirms their choices.

I suspect that there might be an error in the code for the process end event, which removes the listeners at the end. But the two messages in the process end event code are never logged.
Can anyone let me know what's wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance.

```
function DefaultWelcomeIntent(agent){
  console.log("mongoose.connection.readyState: ",mongoose.connection.readyState);
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1) {
    mongoose.connect(dbURI,{ useUnifiedTopology: true ,useNewUrlParser: true}, () => {
    console.log("Mongoose state: ", mongoose.connection.readyState);
  })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("catch error: ", e);
    });
  }

  mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log("Mongoose is connected");
  });

  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log("Mongoose is disconnected");
    process.exit(1);
  });

  mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {//any error
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ', err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    console.log("app is terminating");
    mongoose.connection.close(function () {
      console.log('Mongoose default connection closed');
      mongoose.connection.removeAllListeners();  
      process.exit(0); // terminates a node js process with 'success code'.
    });
  });

// some additional code in welcome intent to respond to user
}

function database_request1(context_parameters) {  
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1) {
    mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useUnifiedTopology: true ,useNewUrlParser: true},() => {
      console.log("Mongoose state: ", mongoose.connection.readyState);
  })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("catch error: ", e);
      });
  }

  mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log("Mongoose is connected");
  });

  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log("Mongoose is disconnected");
    process.exit(1);
  });

  mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ', err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    console.log("app is terminating");
    mongoose.connection.close(function () {
      console.log('Mongoose default connection closed');
      mongoose.connection.removeAllListeners(); 
      process.exit(0); 
    });
  });
// some additional code to save data to DB
}
```

[Log Screenshot](http://shameladdas.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Screen-Shot-2020-08-23-at-8.02.25-PM.png)

Comment: Where is this code located in the rest of your code? Offhand, it sounds like it is being called every time you get a Dialogflow request or something similar.

Comment: @Prisoner thanks for your comment. I updated my code above to show where these events are being called. They are called only in two areas: in the welcome intent and in a function that is being called at the end to save the data to DB.

Comment: You should not be making a new database connection on each request. Instead you should create a database connection once at startup and then use that same connection in the rest of your code. Your database driver will usually handle connection pooling etc internally

Comment: @slebetman thanks, i updated the code above to show that i am creating the connection only at startup and then at the end when the data are being pushed to DB.