# Register same event listener twice or two different listeners in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, eventemitter

I have a Node JS express app with four connection events (connected/ disconnected/ error/ process end). I am registering listeners for these events twice in the code: once in the beginning when the app connects to mongoDB (see function foo1 in the scenarios below) and once at the end when the data are saved to the DB (see function foo2). Is it better to register the same listener for each event twice (scenario 1 below) or register two different listeners for each event (scenario 2)? Note that I am also removing the listeners at the end of the code to prevent memory leaks.

**Scenario 1:**

```
function connected_listener(){
  console.log("Mongoose is connected");
}
function disconnected_listener(){
  console.log("Mongoose is disconnected");
  process.exit(1);
}
function error_listener(err){
  console.log('Mongoose connection error: ', err);
  process.exit(1);
}
function gracefulExit() { //code executed when SIGINT fired
  mongoose.connection.close(function () {
    console.log("app is terminating");
  mongoose.connection.removeAllListeners();
  process.exit(0);
  });
}
function foo1(){ //code in the beginning when the app connects to mongoDB
  mongoose.connection.on('connected', connected_listener);
  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', disconnected_listener);
  mongoose.connection.on('error', error_listener);
  process.on('SIGINT', gracefulExit);
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1){
    mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useUnifiedTopology: true ,useNewUrlParser: true},() => {
      console.log("Mongoose state: ", mongoose.connection.readyState);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("catch error: ", e);
    });
  }
//additional code
}
// additional functions//
function foo2(){ //code at the end when the app saves data to mongoDB
  mongoose.connection.on('connected', connected_listener);
  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', disconnected_listener);
  mongoose.connection.on('error', error_listener);
  process.on('SIGINT', gracefulExit);
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1){
    mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useUnifiedTopology: true ,useNewUrlParser: true},() => {
    console.log("Mongoose state: ", mongoose.connection.readyState);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("catch error: ", e);
    });
  }
//code to remove mongoose listeners
mongoose.connection.removeListener('connected', connected_listener);
mongoose.connection.removeListener('connected', connected_listener);
mongoose.connection.removeListener('disconnected', disconnected_listener);
mongoose.connection.removeListener('disconnected', disconnected_listener);
mongoose.connection.removeListener('error', error_listener);
mongoose.connection.removeListener('error', error_listener);
mongoose.connection.removeListener('SIGINT', gracefulExit);
mongoose.connection.removeListener('SIGINT', gracefulExit);
//some additional code here to save to mongoDB
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
function connected_listener1(){
  console.log("Mongoose is connected");
}
function connected_listener2(){
  console.log("Mongoose is connected");
}
function disconnected_listener1(){
  console.log("Mongoose is disconnected");
process.exit(1);
}
function disconnected_listener2(){
  console.log("Mongoose is disconnected");
  process.exit(1);
}
function error_listener1(err){
  console.log('Mongoose connection error: ', err);
  process.exit(1);
}
function error_listener2(err){
  console.log('Mongoose connection error: ', err);
  process.exit(1);
}
function gracefulExit1() { //code executed when SIGINT fired
  mongoose.connection.close(function () {
  console.log("app is terminating");
  mongoose.connection.removeAllListeners();
  process.exit(0);
  });
}
function gracefulExit2() { //code executed when SIGINT fired
  mongoose.connection.close(function () {
  console.log("app is terminating");
  mongoose.connection.removeAllListeners();
  process.exit(0);
  });
}
function foo1(){ //code in the beginning when the app connects to mongoDB
  mongoose.connection.on('connected', connected_listener1);
  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', disconnected_listener1);
  mongoose.connection.on('error', error_listener1);
  process.on('SIGINT', gracefulExit1);
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1){
    mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useUnifiedTopology: true ,useNewUrlParser: true},() => {
      console.log("Mongoose state: ", mongoose.connection.readyState);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
    console.log("catch error: ", e);
    });
  }
//additional code
}
// additional functions//
function foo2(){ //code at the end when the app saves data to mongoDB
  mongoose.connection.on('connected', connected_listener2);
  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', disconnected_listener2);
  mongoose.connection.on('error', error_listener2);
  process.on('SIGINT', gracefulExit2);
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1){
    mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useUnifiedTopology: true ,useNewUrlParser: true},() => {
    console.log("Mongoose state: ", mongoose.connection.readyState);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("catch error: ", e);
    });
  }
//code to remove mongoose listeners
  mongoose.connection.removeListener('connected', connected_listener1);
  mongoose.connection.removeListener('connected', connected_listener2);
  mongoose.connection.removeListener('disconnected', disconnected_listener1);
  mongoose.connection.removeListener('disconnected', disconnected_listener2);
  mongoose.connection.removeListener('error', error_listener1);
  mongoose.connection.removeListener('error', error_listener2);
  mongoose.connection.removeListener('SIGINT', gracefulExit1);
  mongoose.connection.removeListener('SIGINT', gracefulExit2);
  //some additional code here to save to mongoDB
}
```

Comment: What problem are you solving?

Comment: This app is a webhook for a Dialogflow chatbot. My objective is to add listeners to make sure mongoose is connecting properly to store the user parameters and then to remove those listeners at the end once all data have been saved. As there will be many users interacting with the chatbot, I don't want to leave behind many listeners that might lead to a memory leak.

Comment: I don't think it matters how you define the listeners but I also don't understand why your listeners affect any state.

Comment: @D.SM Before, when I was not removing the listeners, I was receiving a warning: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553881/maxlistenersexceededwarning-in-node-js-express-app?noredirect=1#comment112392500_63553881

Comment: The listeners tell you about state changes. My guess is whatever you are trying to do with them that causes you to connect/disconnect from within a listener is based on some faulty assumptions/understanding and you should redo your achitecture.